# Permissions When Attempting to install mongodb

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I am trying to install mongoDB and need to tap their repo with homebrew. However, every time I run the command, I get a permission error. I am on macOs if that helps

I tried running it with and without sudo and get errors either way.

```sh
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

It should just tap the repo

Without Sudo-

```
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

With Sudo-

```
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
```

Comment: nevermind, I have found the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had the change the permissions of the

```sh
/usr/local/Homebrew
```

directory so that it could be edited by anyone. I did this using the GUI, but you could do it using this command

```sh
cd /usr/local && sudo chown -R 777 Homebrew
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Catalina, then give the owner user permission to "Homebrew" folder:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Homebrew/
```